# Computing $\sum_{k=1}^n k 2^k$ by hand

Tags: summation, exponential-function, closed-form

I'm wondering how to determine the closed form for this sum:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k 2^k$$

I'm aware that it is $ 2 (2^n n - 2^n + 1)$ through Wolfram|Alpha, but I wonder how this would be done by hand. Searches for "summations of products" yielded no results, so I'm assuming that there isn't an easy way to determine summations that include products of functions.

How would one approach computing this summation without the help of technology?

Comment: Compute $\sum_{k=1}^n (k+1) 2^k$ instead. What's the derivative of $\sum_{k=1}^n x^{k+1}$ ?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico–geometric_sequence

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-inftyn1xn) also.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Broken link :P Use proper link formatting `[description here](link here)`

Comment: You can also transform this into a first order recurrence relation, find an initial value, and compute that